# Interpreting reference to the return function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

This [JavaScript RegExp constructor Property
❮ JavaScript RegExp Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_constructor.asp)
article (on w3school's) says

> The return value is a reference to the function, not the name of the function:

What does the above actually mean? 
AFAIU, the following code, returns (alerts) the whole function definition and not a reference or is it? I am not sure.

```
 var patt = new RegExp("Hello World", "g");
 alert(patt.constructor);
```

Can some please make the above statement more clearer, preferably with an example.

Thanks
dk

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, functions are a type of object.

Objects are always addressed by reference.

---

```
var foo = {};
```

The value of `foo` is a reference to the new object.

```
var bar = foo;
```

The value of `bar` is a reference to the same object.

```
function baz() {

}
```

The value of `baz` is a reference to the function object.

```
var aaa = baz;
```

The value of `aaa` is a reference to the same object.

---

> AFAIU, the following code, returns (alerts) the whole function definition and not a reference or is it?

The reference is used to get the function. The function's `toString()` method is called implicitly. That string is alerted.

---

JavaScript doesn't use *explicit* references. You just deal with references whenever you deal with an object.

Take this for comparison:

```js
 var one = new RegExp("Hello World", "g");
 var two = new RegExp("Goodbye World", "g");
 one.constructor.foo = "Value of foo";
 alert(two.constructor.foo);
```

… because you deal in references, the two different `constructor` properties point to the same object.

Comment: *"...the two different `constructor` properties..."* They're not different `constructor` properties, they're the same inherited property.

Answer (score 0):

As was stated before in JavaScript functions are a special type of object. Objects are passed by reference. This means that functions are passed by reference when passed at all.

What the statement tries to say it that what is passed is actually the function itself, and not only the name (as in *a string*) of the function.

```
var patt = new RegExp("Hello World", "g");
patt.constructor === RegExp;      // true
typeof RegExp;                    // function
RegExp.name;                      // RegExp
typeof RegExp.name;               // string
```